# Redirect https to http - google index

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a problem that needs a fix asap. Last week i had my site on https, google indexed it as it was and now i removed the ssl certificate, but all the links are indexed as https and do not work. I need a redirect or something similar that will transform https in http ... so that the links will work untill google reindexes the corect links. I am using a wordpress site if it has anything to do with it.

I already tried using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.machomen\.ro$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://machomen.ro/$0 [R,L]
```

and everything else i could find for htaccess but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't redirect https to http if you don't have a valid certificate for https:

If the visitor came first to the https version, the browser have first to establish a secure link before you can answer a redirect.

So you need to install again a certificate on your website.